# How does "Unfriend Finder" work? (Chrome Extension that somehow modifies Facebook's webpage)

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

I'm looking at [unfriendfinder](https://www.unfriendfinder.com/home) and am curious how it would hook into the Facebook page and   what the Chrome Extension is doing.

Is this a development pattern I could follow for my own applications (where I require Chrome and modify the Facebook home page).

How difficult would this be to port to other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

It uses the [userscript](http://userscripts.org/) concept, where you write a script in JavaScript to modify a website through the DOM.

Pretty much all web browsers support userscripts, Chrome does it natively, and Firefox uses the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) extension. Also checkout [Greasespot](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page) for a good resource on userscripts.